# How to compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{x+1} + e^{3-x}}$?

Tags: calculus

How to compute $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{x+1}  + e^{3-x}}$?

My partial solution: 
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{x+1}  + e^{3-x}} = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{dx}{e^{3-x}(1  + e^{2x-2})} \\
= \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{x-3}dx}{1  + e^{2x-2}}.
$$
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Put $t = e^{x-1} \to e^{2x-2} = t^2\to I = \dfrac{1}{e^2}\cdot \displaystyle \int_{e^{-1}}^\infty \dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}$

Answer (score 3):

It is natural to let $y=e^x$. Then $dy=e^x\,dx$, so $dx=\frac{1}{y}\,dy$. Thus we want
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{1}{e\cdot y+e^3 \cdot \frac{1}{y}}\,dy,$$
which simplifies to
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{e}\cdot\frac{1}{y^2+e^2}\,dy.$$
Let $y=et$, and we are nearly finished.